# importance of Context in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

i read context in android current state of the application/object

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondaryActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

in the place of `this` we can use `getApplicationContext()`
but in an

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hai",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

we can't use `this` here i mean in `getApplicationContext()` why this also refers to the current object ,hence am confused about `this` and `context` help me to study this,an reference share me..

Comment: i already read that one ,but didnt get reason of that qn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `this` to method, you mean that `this` reference is an instance of `Context`, so if you are in Activity you can pass this instead of Context. But when you are in anonymous class:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(){
         //here this is a reference to OnClickListener instance
     }
```

To pass `Context` in `onClick` method you can write

```
MyActivity.this
```

Comment: No enclosing instance of the type MyActivity is accessible in scope :MyActivity.this

Comment: MyActivity should be replaced with your activity class name.

Comment: oh i forgot that,youre right thanks

Answer (score 1):

Activity is a sublcass of context so all `Activity` objects are also a `Context`:

```
android.content.Context
   ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
       ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
           ↳    android.app.Activity
```

So if you can't use `this` than it means `this` is not an instance of an `Context` class or its subclass.